# Flutter not working anymore after I ran flutter channel master

Tags: flutter

I'm using Macbook.
After I ran flutter channel master and flutter upgrade, I got the error below.

**Please is there any solution for this?**

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for sysctl.
#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:124:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.runSync 
(package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:91:30)
#2      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:649:37)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:548:14)
#4      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:649:12)
#5      _DefaultProcessUtils.runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:421:51)
#6      _MacOSUtils.hostPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:305:25)
#7      _MacOSUtils.name (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:291:123)
#8      new _DefaultUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/usage.dart:247:18)
#9      new Usage (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/usage.dart:81:9)
#10     runInContext.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:247:20)
#11     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:41)
#12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#13     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#14     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#15     flutterUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:55:35)
```

Comment: try to run "flutter clean" and restart the IDE you are using to reload all.

Comment: Delete the pubspec.lock

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to first try to find the installation of the **sysctl** in your system. In some MacOs it is located in /usr/sbin. So, how to discovery it? Do the following command in the teminal: `whereis sysctl` or `which sysctl`. The result would be something like: `/usr/sbin/sysctl`.
After this, add it to the PATH.

```
# Adding /usr/sbin/ to path
PATH=/usr/sbin/:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Copy and paste it into the ~/.bash_profile either the ~/.zshrc file.
Restart your terminal (close it and open again) and run `flutter doctor`. Is done!